# Resolving Conflicts in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to [learn Mercurial](http://hginit.com/02.html) but am struggling to figure out how to deal with the situation of a central repository with two clones, and changes simultaneously made in the clones. Here's what I did:

1.I created a repository in a folder (`central`), and then cloned it to two other folders (`al`, `bob`).
2. Added a file (text.txt) to `al`, committed it
3. Changed the file in `al`, committed it
4. Pushed `al` to `central`
5. Pulled `central` into `bob`, updated
6. Changed file in `bob`, committed, pushed to `central`
7. Pulled `central` into `al`, updated

Here's the part where my question comes in ... 
8. I changed a file in `al`, committed AND
9. changed the same file in `bob`, committed
10. I pushed `bob` to `central`
11. Now, when I pull `central` to `al` I get the message

> added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
>   (run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)

I understand what's going on re: the two heads. But when I then merge I get the message

```
merging test.txt
Unsupported file type .txt
merging test.txt failed!
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 1 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg update -C .' to abandon
```

I'm struggling to figure out what to do here ... The changes I made to the file do not conflict with each other.

Comment: What do you get if you do a hg diff --git on the file between the two revisions?

Comment: @Nanhydrin -- just a message saying `[command completed successfully...]`

Answer (score 1):

While you think that changes do not conflict with each other, Mercurial doesn't agree.

To reslove conflict you would have to open `test.txt` file and manually resolve conflict in places where Mercurial has left conflict tags (<<<<<<< >>>>>>>), save corrected file and then run `hg resolve` After merge is resolved you should commit changes with `hg commit`

You can find more details in [Resolving conflicts in Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialConflict)

Comment: Thanks for responding!...I checked and confirmed test.txt did not show the conflict tags you mentioned (before or after I ran `hg merge`. I played around with TortoiseHg's settings for merge and diff tools, too (although the internal defaults should create the tags you mentioned).

Comment: I would just go with `hg resolve` to move forward, and then fix content of `test.txt` if it is not right after merge is complete, then `push` to `central` and `pull` from `bob` before things diverge again

Comment: Sometimes if things really go haywire I would go with ditching "broken" repository and doing fresh clone if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As @dalija-prasnikar suggests, there's a difference you're just not finding it.  Try a `hg diff` and see if anything's visible to you or post it in your question.  Another possibility is file permission -- the execute bit is tracked and some filesystems swizzle those on you, and if the two branches disagree you might be asked to resolve it.

Comment: I tried an `hg diff` and nothing showed up. For the heck of it I tried repeating everything but using a different file extension. Completely unrelated, the next time I pulled from `central` Mercurial again mentioned the (still) unresolved conflict--but this time recognized it, popped up a window re: resolving the conflict, showed the issue in an `hg diff`, etc. ... The whole thing is weird to me. I don't know if it's a bug of some sort or just my lack of knowledge. (And thanks for your reply, BTW!)

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial tries to use the merging-tool you have configured (see .hgrc) and this tool says: `Unsupported file type .txt` and probably does nothing with the file. Therefore a diff does not show anything (your file remains unchanged, but the difference to the other branch actually exists. Perhaps you can see the diff using the revision numbers:
`hg log -l 5` will show you the last 5 commits. Use the revisions to call `hg diff -r $REV_FROM_AL -r $REV_FROM_BOB`

To resolve you have to

- edit the file `text.txt` including what you want from the 2 versions (see diff above)
- *mark as resolved*: `hg resolve -m text.txt`
- commit the changes

I use a script written by Noel Burton-Krahn to manually merge in my preferred editor. On conflicting-errors the "simple version" of this script saves 3 files: original/parent, mine, other-version.
See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergingManuallyInEditor

PS: sometimes working in different plattforms (Windows/Linux) I got empty diffs (on Windows) that I resolved doing a `hg revert` on the file.